# netbeans 12.0 spring boot plugin missing

Tags: spring, netbeans, plugins

Good day,

My Netbeans 11.3 auto updated to Netbeans 12.0 recently and i cannot find the spring boot plugin, is there a way to install spring plugin manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you talk about this plugin: https://netbeans-vm.apache.org/pluginportal/catalogue/?id=4

In order to install it manually, you can go to the GitHub release page directly (https://github.com/AlexFalappa/nb-springboot/releases) and download the .nbm file.

Then open NetNeans 12, and go to Tools > Plugins. In the new window, go to "Downloaded" tab, click "Add plugins..." and provide the .nbm file you just downloaded :
[image: Window for downloaded plugins installation]

Done!

You should now see the NB SpringBoot plugin in the "Installed" tab, under "User installed plugins" category :
[image: SpringBoot plugin installed]